# Choose closest item to user

Tags: ios, swift3, mapkit

I have figured out how to find locations around the user using a key word. Now my struggle is how to automatically choose the nearest item, any ideas as to how I could accomplish that? Thank you, anything is greatly appreciated.
`

```
//Map
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
var matchingItems: [MKMapItem] = [MKMapItem]()

let manager = CLLocationManager()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let location = locations[0]

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    matchingItems.removeAll()
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Hopital"
    request.region = map.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error occured in search: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else if response!.mapItems.count == 0 {
            print("No matches found")
        } else {
            print("Matches found")

            for item in response!.mapItems {
                print("Name = \(item.name)")
                print("Phone = \(item.phoneNumber)")

                self.matchingItems.append(item as MKMapItem)
                print("Matching items = \(self.matchingItems.count)")

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    })

    self.map.showsUserLocation = true

}
```

New code after edit, error code on line marked with the *

> extension Array where Iterator.Element : MKAnnotation {

```
func closest(to fixedLocation: CLLocation) -> Iterator.Element? {
    guard !self.isEmpty else { return nil}

    var closestAnnotation: Iterator.Element? = nil
    var smallestDistance: CLLocationDistance = 9999999

    for annotation in self {

        *let locationForAnnotation = CLLocation(latitude: annotation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: annotation.coordinate.longitude)
        let distanceFromUser = fixedLocation.distance(from:locationForAnnotation)

        if distanceFromUser < smallestDistance {
            smallestDistance = distanceFromUser
            closestAnnotation = annotation
        }
    }

    // now you can do whatever you want with the closest annotation
    return closestAnnotation
    }
}
```

and the error reads "value of type 'Element' has no member 'coordinate'

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

```
extension Array where Iterator.Element == MKAnnotation {

    func closest(to fixedLocation: CLLocation) -> Iterator.Element? {
        guard !self.isEmpty else { return nil}

        // create variables you'll use to track the smallest distance measured and the
        // closest annotation
        var closestAnnotation: Iterator.Element? = nil
        var smallestDistance: CLLocationDistance = 9999999

        // loop through your mapview's annotations (if you're using a different type of annotation,
        // just substitude it here)
        for annotation in self {
            // create a location object from the coordinates for the annotation so you can easily
            // compare the two locations
            let locationForAnnotation = CLLocation(latitude: annotation.coordinate.latitude, longitude:annotation.coordinate.longitude)

            // calculate the distance between the user's location and the location you just created
            // from the annoatation's coordinates
            let distanceFromUser = fixedLocation.distance(from:locationForAnnotation)

            // if this calculated distance is smaller than the currently smallest distance, update the
            // smallest distance thus far as well as the closest annotation
            if distanceFromUser < smallestDistance {
                smallestDistance = distanceFromUser
                closestAnnotation = annotation
            }
        }

        // now you can do whatever you want with the closest annotation
        return closestAnnotation
    }
}
```

## Solution 2 (using `sorted`)

```
extension Array where Iterator.Element == MKAnnotation {

    func closest(to fixedLocation: CLLocation) -> Iterator.Element? {

        return self.sorted { (annotation1, annotation2) -> Bool in
            let location1 = CLLocation(latitude: annotation1.coordinate.latitude, longitude:annotation1.coordinate.longitude)
            let location2 = CLLocation(latitude: annotation2.coordinate.latitude, longitude:annotation2.coordinate.longitude)

            let distanceFromUser1 = fixedLocation.distance(from: location1)
            let distanceFromUser2 = fixedLocation.distance(from: location2)

            return distanceFromUser1 < distanceFromUser2
        }.first

    }
}
```

Utility extension:

```
extension MKMapView {
    func closestAnnotationToUser() -> MKAnnotation? {
        let userLoc = CLLocation(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        return annotations.closest(to: userLoc)
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
// Works on any [MKAnnotation]
let nearestPin = self.map.annotations.closest(to: self.map.userLocation.location)

// OR

let nearestPin = self.map.closestAnnotationToUser()
```

*Solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/25517497/2124535 (objc)*

Comment: Im using the first solution and its working perfectly so far but I cant get past one error code, any Ideas? I have posted the error and code on top. Thank you again, im thinking it has something to do with using "annotation.coordinate...." and the annotation part is calling the error out

Comment: I just tested it on Xcode 8.3.3 + iOS 10.3 and Xcode 9 + iOS 11 beta 7 and it worked. Not sure why your project isn't compiling it.

Comment: Weird, okay I probably messed up, thank you for checking!